# CSS sprite with parameter?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I am confused, it looks like parameter, but doesn't show any damage if I change `?v=4` to `?v=1` or `2` or `3` or `5`. I don't even know what to call it.

Is it for javascript? and/or tracking reference? What is it's purpose then. Image loads without it.

Here's image showing it:

[image: showing stackoverflow logo background]

For this : (chrome) right click on stackoverflow logo above and click 'Inspect Element'.

Comment: it's a versioning parameter. each time the sprite is updated, the designer updates the parameter too - to force all browsers to download the new png.

Comment: !!! Now, I remember. I read it somewhere.  Thanks ptriek.

Comment: Is there any other usage for it else versioning?

Comment: helps in invalidating the cache too I guess. So that cached-image can be replaced soon.

Answer (score 0):

its done for versioning... Maybe the image is generated by some script in the backend. Or its simply to avoid caching. Basically, you can to this with every image. If you change the param, the image is gonna reload form the server,